# Window.top undefined in WorkerGlobalScope

Tags: javascript, dom, web-worker

Just wanted to know why window.top returns "undefined" in  WorkerGlobalScope.

I read on MDN website, but it does not tell anything about this scenario.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Just wanted to know why window.top returns "undefined" in WorkerGlobalScope.

It doesn't, it throws an error because `window` is not a defined global in WorkerGlobalScope.

Workers have a completely different global environment from the page that spawned them. That environment doesn't have the `window` global, which is specific to environments within a browser window. Workers aren't in a browser window, although they're spawned by code that is.